# 3D point to UnstructuredGrid

Tags: point, mesh, vtk

Can we obtain an UnstructuredGrid from 3D point array with values that exceed a threshold? I want to apply mesh to 3D point array. Is it possible? What kind of filters/functions do we need to do this process?

Best regards.

Comment: The question is a little vague. Can you narrow it down a little? Thanks.

Comment: 3D point data (100*100*100) to http://www.google.com.tr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.itu.edu.tr%2Fevrene%2FGPR_karstik_bosluk.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.itu.edu.tr%2Fevrene%2FGPR.html&h=247&w=450&tbnid=sRH4Acrx7Dhu2M%3A&zoom=1&docid=2qY0hOk85rDgrM&ei=aCkHVIPOOKTqyQPTm4GYBg&tbm=isch&ved=0CCUQMygdMB04ZA&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=801&page=4&start=100&ndsp=36